# Executing EXE with wildcard from psexec

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008-r2, psexec

I'm writing a few scripts that I am using to integrate with bamboo for some continuous integration improvements and I've run into a bit of a snag.

I'm currently trying to run a `psexec` command that installs the latest build on the remote machine but I dont necessary know the revision number. For example, the remote exe file could be `Installer-3.1.xxxxx.exe` where the xxxxx changes.

I tried running the command with `Installer-3.1.*.exe` but it takes it as literal in Windows.

I'm not overly familiar with Windows command prompt and am more used to Linux at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Mark [**Russinovich**](http://blogs.technet.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=psexec&sections=5236) has more help on the Technet site or on SysInternals site
**http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html** gives syntax.
Windows will automatically invoke the appropriate latest version of installer if installed.

Comment: That's a start. I am now using instead of a wildcard I invoke the -c argument before the file I copied over to the remote machine to install. Only issue now is I need to run the executable in silent mode.

Example is Installer-3.1.98235.exe /S